# Passing Multiple Values to Parameter in iReport 4.01

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Am working on *iReport 4.0.1*

Can I pass multiple values to parameter like:

```
select name,id from temp where name in (xxx,zzz,yyy)
```

Can I implement using *iReport 4.0.1*. I even tried by using `$X{In, column name, parameter name}` this syntax but am unsuccessful.

Could anyone help, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem as follows:

```
select name,id from temp where name in ($P!{parameter_name})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter with parameter class `java.util.Collection`. Lets assume that the parameter name is **tmpNames**. (`$P{tmpNames}`)
And put your parameter into the query like below :

```
select name,id from temp where $X{IN,name,tmpNames};
```

Do not forget to pass a collection of names to the `tmpNames` parameter.

```
tpNames=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("abc","acd","ade"));

...

map.put("tmpNames",tpNames);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a String parameter in your Jasper Report, like `customers`
2. Prepare a query in Jasper Designer, like pass parameter as `$P!{customers}`, enter `!` after $P

   ```
   SELECT
        *
   FROM
        tblInvoice
   WHERE
        date BETWEEN $P{startDate} AND $P{endDate}
   AND
        cust_name IN ($P!{customers})
   ```
3. Finally, pass the string from java code as like:

   ```
   String customers = "\'xxx\',\'zzz\',\'yyy\'";
   Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<>();
   parameter.put("customers", customers);
   ```